# How to replicate schema changes from local database to a remote?

Tags: sql-server, remote

I was working with some big database and I want to replicate local changes from a local database (I just added some columns to a few tables) to a remote database on other server.

The thing is that I can't backup data and create new schema and after that put in all data again cause the data is huge like 10.GB, I think there should be a better way of doing this.

So what is the properly way of doing this?

Note:
When I was doing changes at MS SQL Server Management Studio using the design view the IDE don't give me any sql log with changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, click the `Generate Scripts` button and then execute the generated SQL script at both the local and remote databases.

[image]

For the changes you made locally, that you now want to replicate to the remote server, you'll need to either recreate them manually on the remote server or use a tool to identify the differences, such as [RedGate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) or [Visual Studio's Schema Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx) tool.

There are other methods, but I think these are likely going to be the easiest approach for you.

Finally, the "proper" way to handle changes like this is to tap into some release management methodologies.  This topic can get pretty complex depending on your needs, but a good primer can be found [here](http://www.releasemanagement.org/2016/02/database-version-control-tools/) along with a listing of some of the tools available on the market.